# TCPDF Footer appearing in the middle and end of page at the same time

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I can't determine the cause of this. I created a customize footer for my pdf pages. But there are cases wherein the footer appears in the middle and end of the page. Does anyone encounter the same issue? and how did you resolve this issue? I have attached a screenshot of the footer displayed in the pdf file generated.

[image]

I did try to display the current X and Y of the footer using getX() and getY(). both display the same value for the footer in the middle and the end of page which is weird.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.